# Show that, if for every non-denumerable $\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{M} \not\models \Gamma$, then $\Gamma$ is unsatisfiable.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification, model-theory

**Show that, if for every non-denumerable $\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{M} \not\models \Gamma$, then $\Gamma$ is unsatisfiable.**

**Or alternatively, if for every uncountable $\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{M} \not\models \Gamma$, then $\Gamma$ is unsatisfiable.**

The following is my proposed proof, I would like to get some verification on whether it works. I would also be very interested in alternative proofs.

Let's prove this by contradiction. Assume $\Gamma$ has no non-denumerable models. Then supposing that $\Gamma$ has a model gets us a contradiction.

Taking non-denumerable to mean either finite or non-enumerable.

1. Suppose $\Gamma$ is satisfiable, and so has a model.
2. Then $\Gamma$ either has an enumerable or non-enumerable model.
3. If $\Gamma$ has a non-enumerable model, then we have a contradiction.
4. If $\Gamma$ has an enumerable model, then it has either a finite or denumerable model.
5. If $\Gamma$ has a denumerable model, then by Upward lowenheim skolem theorem, $\Gamma$ also has a non-denumerable model. This contradicts our assumption.
6. If $\Gamma$ has a finite model, then this contradicts our assumption too.
7. Therefore, $\Gamma$ is unsatisfiable.

I think this question reveals the inexpressibility of first-order theories. Particularly pertinent to this proof is how they can't express that they only have finite models. But they can express that they have models of cardinality, say, 5. All is fine so long as they are specifying integers. Once we go beyond specifying particular integers, they can no longer pin down the size of their models. "I only have finite models", "I only have denumerable models" or "I only have non-denumerable models" would be some inexpressible statements in first-order logic.

Comment: You yourself said that "they can express that they have models of cardinality, say, 5"... If so how can the sentence in the title be correct? Let $Γ$ be $∀x∀y (x=y)$, then $\{\emptyset\}⊨Γ$ every uncountable structure, ${\cal {N}}\not⊨Γ$.

You didn't specify in any place that $Γ$ need to have model of unbounded large natural number cardinality

Comment: If you are going to continue to use “denumerable” in this way (despite several complaints in the past), please at least call attention to it. Really you should just find-and-replace with “countably infinite”.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah, I guess it's because I'm coming from a philosophical background. But if you think others will find it easier to understand if I use countably infinite instead, then in future I will change my terminology.

Comment: @ℋolo Yeah, this seems problematic. The question is definitely correct. Maybe my approach is flawed, but how would you show it?

Comment: @HarryRothschild I gave a concrete counter example that shows that this question is wrong

Comment: @ℋolo The question is not wrong... they are confusingly using 'denumerable' to mean 'countably infinite'. It is true that every satisfiable theory has either a finite or an uncountable model.

Comment: In that case, your 1-4 steps prove this statement

Comment: @HarryRothschild Yes I think it will make it easier to understand. Both a commenter and a now-deleted answer assumed denumerable meant countable, and on that assumption the theorem is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could understand the question as, if $\Gamma$ has a countable model, then it also has an uncountable model.

Comment: I guess what's bugging me is how we show if $\Gamma$ has a countably finite model, it also has an uncountable model.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, are you familiar with the Upwards Löwenehim-Skolem Theorem?

Comment: @Reveillark I just know the basics, that if $\Gamma$ has a countably infinite model, it also has an uncountable model.

Comment: Is that not exactly your previous comment, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It's different, I'm taking countably finite to mean countable but finite

Comment: @HarryRothschild A theory with a finite model need **not** have an uncountable model (or even any infinite model): take e.g. $\{\forall x,y(x=y)\}$.

Comment: If a theory has a model then it either has a finite model or an infinite model. If it has an infinite model, then by compactness / Upward LS, it has an uncountable model. Thus if a theory has a model, it has either a finite model or an uncountable model. If 'denumerable' means 'countably infinite', then 'non-denumerable' means 'finite or uncountable'. So if a theory has a model, it has a non-denumerable model, which is the contrapositive of your theorem statement. If 'denumerable' means 'countable', then it is false, since any theory with only finite models has no uncountable models.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Okay, thanks everyone, I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use more standard language below:

- What you call "denumerable" is **countably infinite**.
- What you call "non-denumerable" is **finite or uncountable**.

So the result you're trying to prove can be rephrased via contraposition as:

> Suppose $\Gamma$ is satisfiable. Then either $\Gamma$ has a finite model or $\Gamma$ has an uncountable model.

*The reason we want to split "non-denumerable" up into the two components "finite" and "uncountable" is that they behave totally differently.*

Specifically, we argue as follows. Suppose $\Gamma$ is satisfiable. Let $\mathcal{M}\models\Gamma$. If $\mathcal{M}$ is finite we're done; otherwise, upwards Lowenheim-Skolem applies and there is an uncountable $\mathcal{N}\equiv\mathcal{M}$ (and hence $\mathcal{N}\models\Gamma$).

The key point is that Lowenheim-Skolem can only be applied to an *infinite* structure, so we can't use it to argue that every satisfiable theory has an uncountable model (consider $\{\forall x,y(x=y)\}$).

---

Meanwhile, your specific argument is **incorrect**. It seems you're trying to pass from "$\Gamma$ has a finite model" to "$\Gamma$ has an infinite model" via the construction of $\Gamma^+$ and compactness. However, this doesn't work: $\Gamma^+$ need not be satisfiable. (Again, consider $\Gamma=\{\forall x,y(x=y)\}$.)

What *is* true by compactness is the following:

> If $\Gamma$ has arbitrarily large finite models, then $\Gamma$ has an infinite model.

Finally, it's worth noting that we can have a theory which has a finite model, does not have arbitrarily large finite models, but does have infinite models: take e.g. the axiom $\lambda$ for a linear order with no greatest element and consider $$\{\lambda\vee\forall x,y(x=y)\}.$$

(Incidentally, things are simpler when we restrict attention to **complete** theories. If $\Gamma$ is complete, then either $\Gamma$ has exactly one finite model up to isomorphism or $\Gamma$ has only infinite models.)